# Laravel Charts Package: Class '' not found

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.6

[Larevel Charts](https://charts.erik.cat/) 6.3 is the package for chart. I have read docs. 4 times.  "there is not Aliases new version 6.3 of package" & my laravel version is 5.6

```
use Charts;

 $chart = Charts::database($users, 'bar', 'highcharts')

        ->title("Monthly new Register Users")

        ->groupByMonth(date('Y'), true);
```

ERROR:

> Class 'ConsoleTVs\Charts\Facades\Charts' not found

This line in my *config/app.php*: `'aliases'`
[image]

ERROR In command:

[image]

Comment: I have already done this both command as `php artisan clear compile` & `dump-autoload` but nothing happened. My version of `laravel 5.6` @SevaKalashnikov

Comment: It looks like `Charts` doesn't have a facade implemented and you have to add it via service provider like `ConsoleTVs\Charts\ChartsServiceProvider::class`?

Comment: I have added screen for command of `php artisan clear compile` error

Comment: this is my provider `ConsoleTVs\Charts\ChartsServiceProvider::class,` @SevaKalashnikov already added config/app.php in provider =>

Comment: Remove it from aliases and use it according to documentation provided by Charts

Comment: @SevaKalashnikov actually i spent 18hours behind this thing, till i am failed... after your replied i found hope.

Comment: I have followed Docs. but there is not example what i want, because i watched tutorial in yourtube. all other example are using like this  `Charts::database($users, 'bar', 'highcharts')` @SevaKalashnikov

Comment: Might be an example of an older version or something, you need to use current docs provided since you pulled the most recent version of the package

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181097/discussion-between-kinnari-and-seva-kalashnikov).